# What kafka mean when log that consumer id **** Leave Group

Tags: apache-kafka

We use kafka 2.1.0
Please help me understand what is really going on when in Kafka log we see this message:

```
Preparing to rebalance group some-service in state PreparingRebalance with old  generation 21668 
(__consumer_offsets-47) (reason: removing member consumer-24-f5b9a9b1-ffed-4088-999b-378df9aaa71b on LeaveGroup) 
(kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
```

Does this indicate that Kafka removed a consumer from the group (due to timeout or other things) or consumer left group itself?

Comment: This message occurs frequently? If yes, can be that you have brokers with same id. but, it's possible that your kafka is really rebalancing some data that is retention is timed out to not receive data

Comment: yes rebalance occurs frequently. Just now i check all 5 broker and they didnt have same id.
You say that kafka rebalancing some data, why it may happing ? as i know retention period only need for delete data, why rebalance ? espesially i have log in kafka with this  reason: " removing member consumer-24-f5b9a9b1-ffed-4088-999b-378df9aaa71b on LeaveGroup"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happen because consumer not work properly and not answer to broker by timeouts